# Constructor Error .. ( Strange Error )

Tags: c++

Till Tomorrow The Code Works Good But know it gives a strange error .. 
no default constructor available ..
i really don't understand this error .. Moreover this is first experience with this type of error .. I've searched questions but the discussion on constructor is advanced level..
i'm Intermediate ,,..
Please help check my code .. !!!

```
// error.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Student
{
    const char name[6][11];
    const int id[5];
};


void fetch_id(Student& s, const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "roll no of student: " << i+1 << endl;;
        cin >> s.id[i];
    }

}
void fetch_name(Student& s, const int size)
{

        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {

            cin.getline(s.name[j], 10);
            cout <<"name of student: " << j+1 << endl;  
        }

}

void display_name(Student s, const int size)
{
    cout << "Student Names Are" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {           
        if ( s.name[i] != '\0' )
        cout << s.name[i] << endl;
    }
}

void display_id(Student s, const int size)
{
    cout << "Roll Numbers Are" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << s.id[i] << " || ";
    }
}

int main()
{

    const int size = 5;
    Student s; //  error C2512: 'Student' : no appropriate default constructor available ??
    fetch_id(s, size);
    display_id(s, size);
    cout << '\n';
    fetch_name(s, size);
    cout << '\n';
    display_name(s, size);
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could really improve this question by removing all the irrelevant code.

Comment: you are right juanchopanza, but the function `fetch_id()` and `fetch_name()` are important cause he tries to change the data of the struct.

Comment: When the code worked good until now it should do it today too. If you don't want to way what's the tomorrows state you might tell about the change of today.

Comment: @Zaiborg that would only highlight a different error. The problem with the constructor only needs the `struct` definition and one line in `main()`.

Answer (score 5):

It's because your structure contains constant arrays. They have to be explicitly initialized in a constructor initializer list.

Because of those constant member variables the compiler can't generated a default constructor for you, you have to make one yourself.

Actually, I think you make the arrays constant by mistake as you later in the code try to assign to them, something which can't be done as they are constant.

Remove the `const` part of the member array declarations and it should all work better.

Answer (score 0):

some simple question ... why are you using a 2 dimensional char array and why not `std::string` instead?
the thing with `cin` is, that you have no control of the length of an input, so you will get a buffer overflow soon.
soo long zap